# How to include crystal reports in setup. Exe

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I created a desktop  application  which has crystal reports but whe I install it to another computer crystal  report is not loading....  how do I solve this

Comment: Update your question with details of how you’ve deployed it and clear explanation of what “not loading” actually means.  Any exceptions?

Comment: Solved.... I needed  to install  crystal reports  runtime  engine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.